# Android webview showing old website content instead of new

Tags: javascript, android, caching, webview, android-webview

I am having an issue with webview not fetching fresh pages of my website. I did some thorough search and tried many different techniques but it didn't work till I found this code;

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css?ver=1.3.2'>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js?ver=1.8.3"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js?ver=1.3.2"></script>
<script src="js/my_script.js?ver=201603111428"></script>
```

which simply says to add a new version number to my css etc whenever I make changes and it will load properly on my webview. Shockingly it worked but I have a feeling this shouldn't be the way to go about it, so I wanted to find out if there's a working script I can just add to my webview to make it load the online content each time not cached content?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: @JonasLochmann are you suggesting I try that? I have tried everything suggested on stack and even externally and it's not working...maybe it's how I went about it, I need a fully working script or a step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

The part after `?` character represents actually a log for the changes you made.

These docs should help you understand better why https://semver.org/

This is a good way and a preferred, it can be a simple hash number or an increment or a timestamp as long. But it must mark that the version the browser has cached changed. For that, we append that additional info in the name.

Comment: Ok good practice I get. So everytime I make changes to any of these, I just increase the version number? But for the purpose (i.e. display new content) I am using it for, is it the best way?

Comment: Yes, is a matter of requirements, maybe for CSS `?v2.1.3` is over-engineering a simple `(new Date()).getTime()` is enough you will add to your CSS for each build a new timestamp time. Put on other words, every new production build will have a unique timestamp added to each file, so the browser knows when   a new build was deployed

Comment: @JonasLochmann I agree is not a best practice, that's why I suggested hashing `...simple hash number...` also but that would bring more to configure for the project, But I am curios why is it such a bad practice. As I see it it does the job. 
Also `configure the webserver to tell the client that he should check every time if the content has changed` is a bad practice, since you do a useless request IMO, that is why you add the hash / versioning number not to do another request.